# 最初の質問の際に表示されるメッセージが一部未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

最初の質問をする際にポップアップでメッセージが出ますが、一部未翻訳です。

> 初めてのプログラミング関連の質問をする準備が整いました。コミュニティがお手伝いします！ 最高の回答を得るためのガイダンスがいくつかあります。
> Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered.
>
> 1. 問題を要約してください
> 2. これまでに試したことを説明
> 3. 必要に応じてコードを表示する
>
> サイドバーに更なるヒントがあります。

メタの方も同様のメッセージが出ますが、こちらも未翻訳でした。

> You’re ready to ask your first question and the community is here to help! To get you the best answers, we’ve provided some guidance:
> Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered.
>
> 1. 問題を要約してください
> 2. Provide details and any research
> 3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

以下の string たちのようでした。

- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13886
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/12509
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13215
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13221

@supa さんが翻訳を提案してくださり、先ほど私が承認したので、1 週間以内程度で翻訳が反映されると思います。